# Laravel nova resource update/create ignores model connection

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-nova

- Laravel Version: 5.7.19
- Nova Version: 1.2.1
- PHP Version:  7.2.12

#### Description:

When a resource is using a model with an alternative database connection than the application default only the index page works. When trying to update a record or create one it tries to use the default application database causing an error as the table does not exist. This bypasses the one specified on the corresponding model.

I have tried hooking into model events and setting the connection before update/create but this is not working

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Create model and resource and specify an alternative database connection on the model. `protected $connection = 'another_database';`
2. When updating any resource in nova it will bypass this connection and try to insert/update using the application default connection instead of the `$connection` property set on the model

I expect the alternative database table to be updated but it is bypassing the connection property on the model and using the default application database instead.

Comment: Is this only on `update` or `create` as well? Gave it a try and it was able to successfully create a record for me on my alternate connection.

Comment: edit: I think I may have found the issue. I have a belongsto on the resource which is using another database table, seems to work when this is not present.

`BelongsTo::make('Assigned', 'assigned', 'App\Nova\Admin'),`
public function assigned()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('mysql')->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'admin_id');
    }